# How to loop back to the beginning of a programme - Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I've written a BMI calculator in python 3.4 and at the end I'd like to ask whether the user would like to use the calculator again and if yes go back to the beginning of the code. I've got this so far. Any help is very welcome :-)

```
#Asks if the user would like to use the calculator again
again =input("Thank you again for using this calculator, would you like to try again? Please type y for yes or n for no-")

while(again != "n") and (again != "y"):
    again =input("Please type a valid response. Would you like to try again? Please type y for yes or n for no-")

if again == "n" :
    print("Thank you, bye!")

elif again == "y" :
```

....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the whole code into a loop:

```
while True:
```

indenting every other line by 4 characters.

Whenever you want to "restart from the beginning", use statement

```
continue
```

Whenever you want to terminate the loop and proceed after it, use

```
break
```

If you want to terminate the whole program, `import sys` at the start of your code (**before** the `while True:` -- no use repeating the `import`!-) and whenever you want to terminate the program, use

```
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Where should I put the initial while true? where I want it to go back to?

Comment: @nitrogirl, exactly -- presumably just after `import` statements or other initialization that you *don't* want to repeat over and over.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call the function if the user wants to start again:

```
def calculate():
    # do work
    return play_again()


def play_again():
    while True:
        again = input("Thank you again for using this calculator, would you like to try again? Please type y for yes or n for no-")
        if again not in {"y","n"}:
            print("please enter valid input")               
        elif again == "n":
            return "Thank you, bye!"
        elif again == "y":
            # call function to start the calc again
            return calculate()
calculate()
```